# TestNG option not showing in run

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

I'm new to learning TestNG. I've installed the TestNG plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace and also added external JARs, but none of the options are working. I have the latest Java version and everything is updated. TestNG is also not available in the library after installation. Please help me if I'm missing something